# Mapping Validation Errors To Different Input

Tags: forms, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, simple-form

I'm using Paperclip to handle file upload, but because I'm dealing with very large files I am uploading images directly to S3, before submitting file info via a set of hidden fields.

I do have a file input (called :original_file_url), but this is only used for the S3 upload: I populate a series of hidden fields with the necessary data from the upload when the file upload is complete. This means that the validation errors produced by paperclip, along with my own validation errors, do not map to my file input:

```
"photo.image_content_type"=>["is invalid"], 
"photo.image"=>["is invalid", "can't be blank", "Width must be at least 2460px", "Height must be at least 1640px"]}
```

I'm using simple form:

```
<%= photo_form.input :original_image_url, as: :file, label:false %>
```

With the following template defined in my initializer:

```
  config.wrappers :app, class: 'ControlGroup', error_class: 'is-error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.optional :maxlength
    b.optional :pattern
    b.optional :min_max
    b.optional :readonly
    b.use :label_input
    b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: :div, class: 'ControlGroup-inlineError' }
    b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: 'ControlGroup-hint' }
  end
```

Is there any way to map these errors to that input so they appear as inline errors? Given that I already have the above template which works fine and includes an error field, I just want a way of passing in the error messages to be displayed.

Comment: Added docs to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes, form builder has a method `error`, and you can specify which property you want the error for:

```
photo_form.error :image_content_type
photo_form.error :image
```

Docs [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/simple_form/SimpleForm/FormBuilder#error-instance_method).

Comment: Thanks. So this would involve building the wrapper, input, error and hint manually right?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that - manually in template or manually [in config](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Custom-Wrappers)?

Comment: Sorry. That was unclear. I mean do I have to write a separate template just for that input? Is there no way of passing the error messages into a call to `<%= photo_form.input … %>`? (I've updated the question with more detail).

Comment: You *could* pass an error message, but there is no way to specify condition for displaying error message from template (it happens [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/ac63da0f0b38df82385493f25f649e320b0acb4a/lib/simple_form/components/errors.rb#L4) in simple form and it calls `errors` on the model). You could monkey patch simple form to include a builder method that will cater to your needs.